# Visual Studio Comment Block : Link to internal code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to insert a reference to a code element (i.e a method name, for example) into a comment block ? I am looking for something clickable within VS 2010 (to go from the comment to the referenced element - like the ctr+clik behavior).
Example :

```
 /// <summary>
 /// ITERATES Over Filenames 
 /// </summary>
 /// <see cref="inputbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)"/>
```

(Syntax may be wrong here, it is put just for illustration purpose)

Comment: Have you tried to look at say the .NET framework's xml?

Comment: @leppie : Could you be more precise please ? I would like something with very light footprint (ineally no footprint at all)

Comment: Not built in as far as I know, but I would put good money on assuming there is a [plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) that could do this.